# X-Y Coordinates to box number

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have some grid

Total No. rows = 170

Total No. columns = 200

How do I find cell No.,  if I only know the x-y coordinates in lengths.
Cell no is assigned sequentially, starting from top left .

Comment: First you have find the `row height` and `column width` in pixel.

Comment: ***"it is a physical system"***: I see a 2-D drawing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the attached picture, we do have connected 4 areas with a given geometry. The number of cells in horzontol and vertical direction is given. The cell width and height are defined as well. So pretty much everything is known, to calculate where, in which part and it which cell we are for a given coordinate.

To make life easier, we define the 4 parts (which are equal) in a struct. Then we can determine the margines and the overall positions of each cell.

Basically, we do need to do a lot of calculations. First check, in whicht part we are, then check, in which cell we are and then calculate the overall cell number dependent on the local findings.

Please see below one of the many possible solutions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

constexpr double CellWidth = 35.0;
constexpr double CellHeight = 32.0;
constexpr double OffsetLeft = 22.0;
constexpr double OffsetTop = 20.0;
constexpr double SpaceHorizontal = 60.0;
constexpr double SpaceVertical = 50.0;
constexpr unsigned int TileNumberOfRows = 17U;
constexpr unsigned int TileNumberOfColumns = 10U;
constexpr unsigned int NumberOfTilesHorizontal = 2;
constexpr unsigned int NumberOfTilesVertical = 2;


struct Tile {
    Tile(unsigned int tn);
    std::pair<bool, unsigned int> getCellNumber(const double x, const double y) const;

    unsigned int tileNumber{};

    double posLeft{};
    double posTop{};
    double posRight{};
    double posBottom{};
};

// tielnumer starting with 0. From left to right, then next row
Tile::Tile(unsigned int tn) : tileNumber(tn) {

    // Calculate the index of the tile
    unsigned int tileIndexX = tileNumber % NumberOfTilesHorizontal;
    unsigned int tileIndexY = tileNumber / NumberOfTilesVertical;

    // Calculate X position of tile
    posLeft = 
        // Left margin to paper
        OffsetLeft // - (CellWidth / 2.0) // Unclear if this is the full offset or if we need to substract half the width
        // Depending on the number of tiles
        + tileIndexX * (
            // Tile Width
            TileNumberOfColumns * CellWidth + 
            // Horizontal distance to next tile
            SpaceHorizontal - (CellWidth / 2.0)
        );

    // Calculate Y position of tile
    posTop = 
        // Top Margin to paper
        OffsetTop // - (CellHight / 2.0)    // Unclear if this is the full offset or if we need to substract half the height
        // Depending on the number of tiles
        + tileIndexY * (
            // Tile height
            TileNumberOfRows * CellHeight +
            // Vetical distance to next tile
            SpaceVertical - (CellHeight / 2.0));

    // Right position of tile
    posRight = posLeft + TileNumberOfColumns * CellWidth;

    // Bottom position of tile
    posBottom = posTop + TileNumberOfRows * CellHeight;

}

// Check, if in pos is in tile and at what position
std::pair<bool, unsigned int> Tile::getCellNumber(const double x, const double y) const {

    unsigned int cellNumber{ 0 };
    // Is the position in range of this tile?
    const bool inTile{ (x >= posLeft) && (x <= posRight) && (y > posTop) && (y < posBottom) };

    // If so
    if (inTile) {

        // Calculate row in local tile
        unsigned int col = static_cast<unsigned int>((x - posLeft) / CellWidth + 
            ((tileNumber % NumberOfTilesHorizontal) * TileNumberOfColumns));

        // Calculate col in local tile
        unsigned int row = static_cast<unsigned int>((y - posTop) / CellHeight +
            ((tileNumber / NumberOfTilesVertical) * TileNumberOfRows));

        // And now calculate the overall cell Number
        cellNumber = row * TileNumberOfColumns* NumberOfTilesHorizontal +  col;

    }
    return std::make_pair(inTile, cellNumber);
}

int main(void) {
    const std::vector<Tile> tiles{ Tile(0),Tile(1),Tile(2),Tile(3) };

    // Test values
    const double x{ 740 };
    const double y{ 1100 };

    // Check cell number
    for (const Tile& tile : tiles) {
        if (const auto [isInTile, cellNumber] = tile.getCellNumber(x, y); isInTile) {
            std::cout << "\nTilenumber: " << cellNumber << "\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should this not: `SpaceHorizontal = 60.0 - CellWidth;`